# Gutenberg returns error 500 on save on certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have website which has Gutenberg and it is very important part of it, problem is..
When i enter page and try to save it i get error 500, in console i have  this error in console

```
POST https://myDomain/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/5950 500 ()
POST https://myDomain/wp-admin/post.php?post=5950&action=edit&classic-editor=1&meta_box=1 500 ()
```

and this error in my error log

```
[12-Sep-2018 09:46:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Invalid page template. in /usr/www/users/foodno/v32/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/post-translation/wpml-post-duplication.class.php:99
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/myDomain/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/sitepress.class.php(4219): WPML_Post_Duplication->make_duplicate(5950, 'he')
#1 /usr/www/users/myDomain/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/post-translation/wpml-post-synchronization.class.php(84): SitePress->make_duplicate(5950, 'he')
#2 /usr/www/users/myDomain/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/post-translation/wpml-post-translation.class.php(248): WPML_Post_Synchronization->sync_with_duplicates(5950)
#3 /usr/www/users/myDomain/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/post-translation/wpml-admin-post-actions.class.php(113): WPML_Post_Translation->after_save_post('535', Array, 'en', NULL)
#4 /usr/www/users/myDomain/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): WPML_Admin_Post_Actions->save_post_actions('5950', Objec in /usr/www/users/foodno/v32/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/post-translation/wpml-post-duplication.class.php on line 99
```

I am also using WPML plugin, and on save plugin gets stuck [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/ktgywv)

Loader is in loop...

Thing is, it saves the edited content, but still it returns error 500, i tried debugging and got absolutely nothing

I have googled it of course before asking and i found these as known Gutenberg issues that occured before... None of these did not help.. Does anyone have any suggestion or solution?

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5675
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8410

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

I asked on their git also, and i've got an answer from mr with nickname "brucepearson" and WPML will apparently fix this in next update, here is link to git q/a

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9816